# Laravel composer installation failure

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install Laravel composer in my Windows 10 laptop . It is failing with following error . I am using PHP 7 .

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0

I have removed **;** (semicolon) from beginning of the lines in php.ini containing extension_dir = "ext" , extension=php_interbase.dll and all the above mentioned dlls .

Please can someone help .

Regards,
Sudeshna Bhattacharya

Comment: None of those are errors, they're warnings. You're trying to load `.dll` files that don't exist or are broken. You need to put the semicolons **back**, so these modules aren't loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It has got resolved !!